# How to send an email with attachment using apex (PL/SQL) without storing the attachment in server

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper, oracle-apex-5.1

I wanted to send an email with attachment from the oracle apex workspace, currently i am using the APEX_MAIL package which includes (APEX_ATTACHMENT, APEX_EXPORT functions). But the issue is, we are creating an CSV file and adding it as a mail attachment while sending the email and the attachments are sometimes larger in size which are getting stored in server each time the mail is triggered. This issue is causing a regular maintenance for the DBA to clear the data in the server.

Can anyone suggest is there any alternative for the current approach in order to come out of the issue.

Thanks in advance.

I tried oracle APEX_MAIL but the attachment is saving in database, please provide the alternate approach for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating the attachment CSV in the procedure as a BLOB variable, you can use it as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/aeapi/ADD_ATTACHMENT-Procedure-Signature-1.html#GUID-5B514926-2C0A-40E3-82BB-7E357CB0C927). The only difference would be you should send your blob variable for p_attachment  parameter.

For example:

```
  apex_mail.add_attachment(
    p_mail_id => l_id,
    p_attachment => v_CSV, --the CSV file that you generated and assigned to a variable of type BLOB
    p_filename => l_filename,
    p_mime_type => l_mime_type,
    p_content_id => l_content_id );
```

If you do not generate the CSV file in the package yourself, another approach would be using an intermediate table where you save your attachment file and having a scheduled job that clears that intermediate table on a specified basis. (You can clear the table after the mail is sent but for the logging/reporting it would be better to keep the attachments for a while I believe).

Comment: Hi cengiz sevimli , Thanks for your response , currently we are using the same approach as you have suggested above , but this attachments sometimes contain > 800 MB , may i know when we process the mail and trigger it , where do the attachment go exactly , we were told that they are being stored in the server and consuming lot of space each time mail is triggered , as it requires regular maintenance we are in requiremet of best alternate approach.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand the details here. If you are generating the csv in your code block and attaching it to the mail, then it could be only stored on the internal Apex tables where you can not modify directly. What you can do, try to find the internal table's name under your DB's APEX_20XXX schema then check the data if you can find your lastly sent mail by a key, then delete the blob column of that row.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs , I agree with that and needs to check that with my DBA , we had written our own procedure which would generate the csv in the code block and the it would be attaching it to the mail but we have used UTL_SMTP instead of APEX_MAIL so that it wont be stored in DB But when we run the code procedure we were facing an issue .  Here is the link to the code (4th comment in answers section ) -https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4506198/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-using-apex-pl-sql-without-storing-the-attachment-in-server#latest ,